# Conditional selection of values between columns

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, dplyr

There is a matrix:

```
        A   B

        0   36
        0   4
        4   24
        0   13
        0   11
        11  13
        0   6
        6   20
        0   12
        12  20
        0   11
        0   33
        33  40
        0   31
        0   5
        5   39
        0   7
        7   32
        0   34
        0   13
        0   16
        16  24
```

I would like to:

1) first sort column B (keeping the same pairs between column A and column B) to find 
the smallest value, say x1. In this matrix, x1 is "4".

2) then find values in column A that are greater than or equal to x1.(sorting column A can 
make this step easier. Still keeping the same pairs between column A and column B).
Among the matching paird values in column B for values in column A that are greater 
than or equal to x1, find the value that is the smallest, say x2.

In this matrix, there are 4, 5, 6, 7.... in column A that greater than or equal to x1, 4.
Among the matching pairs between column A and column B, 8 is the smallest.

3) then find values in A that are greater than or equal to x2. 
Among the matching paird values in B for values in A that are greater 
than or equal to x2, find the value that is the smallest, say x3.

4) So on and so forth.

How to use R to accomplish this? to use "dplyr"?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want in the end, but I think you can achieve this task without `dplyr`. I followed what you described in your question using `subset()` and `min()`. Please note I have a data frame here, not a matrix. mydf is your data frame.

```
foo <- mydf[order(mydf$B),] #sort your data frame
x1 <- min(foo$B)

#> x1
#[1] 4

foo2 <- subset(foo, A >= x1)
x2 <- min(foo2$B)

#> x2
#[1] 8

foo3 <- subset(foo2, A >= x2)
x3 <- min(foo3$B)
```

Comment: Hi, jazzurro: it works. Thank you very much. Next I will try to write a loop to achive this task. Thanks again.